# import csv file content into Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import a csv file into Neo4J. I'm following [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) guide and I've already imported a file containing thousands of nodes (users), now I'm trying to import relationships between these nodes but I keep getting this error:

```
Input error: 'TYPE  '
Caused by:'TYPE '
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'TYPE   '
    at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors.valueOf(Extractors.java:152)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.DataFactories$DefaultRelationshipFileHeaderParser.entry(DataFactories.java:361)
```

The csv file I'm trying to import looks like this:

```
ID,:START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE  
1,82513,82718,FRIEND_OF 
2,48635,21154,FRIEND_OF     
3,92784,96648,FRIEND_OF     
4,55215,86714,FRIEND_OF 
.......
```

And in order to import it I use the following command:

```
neo4j-import --into ./ --nodes my_users.csv --relationships my_rels.csv
```

which as I said before correctly imports all the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have trailing spaces or tabs in your file?
Please remove them.

If it is all the same rel-type you can also provide it

on the command line  with `--relationships:FRIEND_OF`.

Comment: Thank you, I had a tab space after each row. I had to remove them